# What is the maximum group size for Dragonstar Arena in Elder Scrolls Online

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Our ESO group is looking at tackling [Dragonstar Arena](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Online:Dragonstar_Arena) in Craglorn.

But the wiki says it's "aimed at groups of four players rather than twelve".

Does that mean it's limited to 4 players like a dungeon & we can't play as a group of 5 or 6? What is the maximum group size for Dragonstar Arena?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game basically knows three sizes for its end game PvE "raid" content,so called trials:

- **Regular trials** are challenges for up to **12 players**:

  - Craglorn: Aetherian Archive
  - Craglorn: Hel Ra Citadel
  - Craglorn: Sanctum Ophidia
  - Reaper's March: Maw of Lorkhaj (requires Thieves Guild DLC)
  - Vvardenfell: Halls of Fabrication (requires Morrowind Chapter)
  - Clockwork City: Asylum Sanctorium (requires Clockwork City DLC)
- **Dragonstar Arena** is a special **4 player** trial you can find in Craglorn.
- **Mahlstrom Arena** is a special **solo** trial you can find in Wrothgar (requires Orsinium DLC).